# Numbers of table

Tags: angular, typescript

Tell me please, how to write in Angular 2 some `@Pipe` or function to add a consecutive number in table? this is a part of my template:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table, table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="12" align="center">none</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>consecutive number</th>
                <th>none</th>
                <th>none</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background: #F5F5F5">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8"></td>
                <td colspan="2">none: none</td>
                <td colspan="2">none: none</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <template ngFor let-list [ngForOf]="lists">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ list.location }}</td>
                </tr>
                <div [hidden]="!list.isVisible">
                    <br>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>none</th>
                                <th>none</th>
                                <th>none</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let new_var of list.hops">
                                <td>{{ new_var.hop_type }}</td>
                                <td>{{ new_var.hop_text }}</td>
                                <td>{{ new_var.id_sl_hop }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I would add consecutive number in `<th>consecutive number</th>`, and add some `@Pipe` or another function in `<td>...<td>`, like `*ngFor` directive, or something else.

Comment: Do you to want get index of actual iteration or I just misunderstand?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use index for getting the consecutive numbers, something like this. Index starts from 0, so you can have index + 1.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of rows; let i= index">
  <td> {{i+1}} </td>
  <td> {{item.name}} </td>
</tr>
```

In your case it should be

```
<template ngFor let-list [ngForOf]="lists" let-i="index"> 

</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! But how syntax `i=index` in this `<template ngFor let-list [ngForOf]="lists">` code?

Comment: You can use it like this  <template ngFor let-list [ngForOf]="lists" let-i="index"> </template>

Comment: @EduardArevshatyan Welcome.